# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined in a .then() => { }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Why can't I navigate to the screen "App" in the following code. I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

```
  async signIn() {
    const { username, password } = this.state
    await Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(user => {
      this.setState({ user })
      this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
      Alert.alert('Signed In Successful!')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error when signing in: ', err)
        Alert.alert('Error when signing in: ', err)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us how `this.props.navigation` is initialised and why you believe it should have a `.navigate` method

Comment: Can you confirm if navigation is a valid object?

Comment: Depending on where and how this method is called, you may want to switch the signature to `signIn = async () => { /* ... */ }`

Comment: how should i initialise this.props.navigation and where?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing promises and await. You either await for the sign in, or remove the async/await and treat it like a promise. Also, it could be that you haven't binded the function so "this" points to undefined.

Either:

```
async signIn = () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state
    let user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
     this.setState({ user })
      this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
      Alert.alert('Signed In Successful!')

  }
}
```

Or

```
signIn = () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state
    Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(user => {
      this.setState({ user })
      this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
      Alert.alert('Signed In Successful!')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error when signing in: ', err)
        Alert.alert('Error when signing in: ', err)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I had to use: signIn = async () => {
    try {
        const user =  await Auth.signIn(username, password);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
        this.setState({ user })
    }
    catch (e) {
         console.error(e);
    }
  };